# When percent change equals to 1

Tags: percentages

To calculate percent change the formula is:
$\frac{Amount \,of\,changes}{Original\, amount}100=\frac{New-Old}{Old}100$

because we want to see how it changes compared to where it was before, now if there is no changes the percent changes must be zero. I am a student in neuroscience field, we always measure biophysical signals change (in our field we call it normalized signals), but these signals are always start from **1**.

Is normalized value and the percent change are the same, and why start from 1 and not 0?

Comment: It may help if you define what "biophysical signals change" is so that one could try to derive a meaning for the value "1" being a minimum value. What would be the max. value?

Comment: biophysical signals: like the signal that define the amount of blood in cerebral area.

Comment: It makes sense to assume that this can't be zero, however, the "normalization process" probably does not just ad the value "1", it is possible based on a statistical formula. Check this if relevant: https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=U7X6nDAtA-MC&pg=PA346&lpg=PA346&dq=normalized+biophysical+signals+change&source=bl&ots=bXZLho_Sjp&sig=ACfU3U1_itVJGY6tAS2avcYpzOyKfDTq-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx98vct-jjAhXSzIUKHYPSBe8Q6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=normalized%20biophysical%20signals%20change&f=false